# page rendering time using fiddler

Tags: performance, networking, fiddler

for an asp.net page we can deduce "time on wire" and ServerTime using this from Statistics in Fiddler:

```
ClientDoneRequest:      09:45:01.433
Determine Gateway:      0ms
DNS Lookup:             0ms
TCP/IP Connect:         0ms
HTTPS Handshake:        0ms
ServerConnected:        09:45:01.316
FiddlerBeginRequest:    09:45:01.435
ServerGotRequest:       09:45:01.435
ServerBeginResponse:    09:45:04.444
GotResponseHeaders:     09:45:04.444
ServerDoneResponse:     09:45:04.457
ClientBeginResponse:    09:45:04.444
ClientDoneResponse:     09:45:04.457
Overall Elapsed:        0:00:03.024
```

**Time on Wire:** (ServerGotRequest-ClientDoneRequest)+(ServerDoneResponse-ServerBeginResponse)
**ServerTime:** ServerBeginResponse-ServerGotResponse
With the above calculation, Time on Wire + ServerTime = Overall Elapsed. Maybe because the client renders in less than one ms. I don't know.

Can we also deduce the **page rendering time** from the same information?

Thank you!

Comment: This would be great! Fiddler is a HAR viewer but doesnt show the onload or oncontentload properties from say an IE XML network trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as far as I know, because Fiddler only acts as proxy. It knows when it handed the data to the browser, but the browser doesn't ping the proxy back with "done rendering".

You can see this information in the console of your browser. Just press F12.

Comment: Thank you. I understand. That makes sense. The problem is that i cannot use anything but IE8 and have not found a way to measure rendering time with the tools at hand. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Bagaboo I found [msfast](https://code.google.com/p/msfast/), _"a browser plugin that help developers to improve their code performance by capturing and measuring possible bottlenecks on their web pages"_. Hope that helps.

Comment: If any tool can be installed you can also take a look at [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/).